# Lookbehind with equal sign

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match

```
===Something===
```

but not

```
====Something====
```

I've come up with the following regular expression

```
Regex.Match("====Something====", @"^\s*===\s*(?<!=====\s*)(?<Title>.*?)\s*===\s*$").Groups["Title"]
```

but it returns

```
=Something=
```

please help what's the issue with the lookbehind pattern.

Comment: Why can't you just use `={1,3}\w+={1,3}`? What am I missing?

Comment: I might not have been clear, something can also be a dot so \w wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more possible solution:

```
(?<!=)===(?!=)(?<Title>.*?)(?<!=)===(?!=)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 3):

Match for the full word! the angle brackets are all important. The below expression translated - if we are talking to the computer is like this: computer, search for a word starting with with three = signs then have any  number of letters then end the word with three equals signs.

Hence if 4 equals signs are there at the start of the word - it won't match.

**string regExpression = @"<={3}(\w+)={3}>";**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // searches for the first specified instance.
        string textToSearchThrough = "===Something===";
        string textToSearchThrough2 = "====Something====";

        // add in \s+ to the below if you wish
        string regexExpression = @"<={3}(\w+)={3}>";
        Regex r = new Regex(regexExpression);

        // change the text to search through to the second variable textToSearchThrough2 if you wish to check
        Match m = r.Match(textToSearchThrough);

        Console.WriteLine(m.Success.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works wrong because you use `.*?` which can also match `=`. So it looks for `===` then accepts anything  (other `=` also), and look for a match which will end with `===` again. So it will match also `===` in `=========` string, and it is not what you are looking for. However if you change `.` (match any character) on `\w` (match word character). Also it would be better to use `\w+` insted `\w*` to avoid maching only `======` without any word (if you don't want to) it should work nad match only `===Something===` even without lookbehind, like:

```
^\s*===\s*(?<Title>\w+?)\s*===\s*$
```

Try it [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/xA6kH1/3).